# Javascript event persistence

Tags: javascript, events

Let us say I have a javascript script that creates callback using setTimeout for 2 hr ahead of time. Now if my javascript fails, is there a way to save the events and restore the events in the next run?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fail'?  What environment is your script running under?

Comment: You will have to track the event via client side storage (cookies, localStorage...) or store the time for the event on the sever. But each time you start the page you will have to recreate the event,.

Comment: I assume this is client side. This would mean the user has to have the page open for 2 hours before the timeout is executed also persistance is difficult for the same reason, page is refreshed any javascript persistance is lost. @Blindman67 suggestion is probably the best way to do it. It might be easier to help if you could expalin the scenario a bit better.

Comment: Yep, what are you trying to do, since a setTimeout on 2 hour delay is probably not the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to make a localstorage variable and check that variable in the beginning of the code. So if your javascript "fails" and you have to restart. You can look if that variable is there and then continue where you left. You probably want to make it a datetime but that's all up to you.

Here is some information about [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Good luck!

Comment: won't I lose the context in which the callback will be executed in this case?

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thanks @Jelmer